# While loop still prints once after EOF in C

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I have to look through a file and take out the information of a student. It all works fine so far, there are 21 lines in the file, the first 20 contain information of a student and the final line contains just a single name. For some reason my while loop continues, sees that there's no information after that last line and stops but it still prints out that last line of the file with other lines of information in the in the output as well.

```
    count = 0;
    
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &average)!= EOF )
    {
        

        if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &average)!= EOF ){
            printf("\n/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
            
            fscanf(fp, "%s", name);
            fscanf(fp, "%s", initial);
            fscanf(fp, "%s", surname);
            
            printf("\n\n\tName: %s \tInitial: %s \tSurname: %s\n", name, initial, surname);
            
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &year);
            fscanf(fp, "%s", coursename);
            fscanf(fp, "%s", group);
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &average);
            
            printf("\n\tYear: %d \tCourse Name: %s \tGroup: %s \tAverage: %d\n", year, coursename, group, average );
            printf("\n\tThis is entry number %d\n", count+1);
            printf("\n/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
            count++;
        }
        if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &average) == EOF ){
             printf("\n\nThank you for using the program\n\nAll of the student records are now displayed\n");
        }

    }

   

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

If the second last line for instance was

> Mike (M) Johnson 3 IT A 66

it would print that out perfectly fine but the final thing in the file the name "John" it would print out

> John Johnson 3 IT A 66

I don't understand firstly why it wouldn't take Mike Johnson's initial and secondly when it shouldn't print that line to begin with? I've tried setting the if statements and while statement to take the name as the end of the file but I think when I use "%s" to find that at the begining it seems to skip everything to the next string in the file over by 1, so Mike's name would become (M), and so on.

Comment: If you're going to use `fscanf`, at least *use* it. You can read multiple values in one call.

Comment: Why do you scan `average` three times on each iteration ?

Comment: Jamie, `fscanf(fp, "%d", &average)` might return 1, 0, or `EOF`.  Why compare against `EOF` instead of 1 for success?

Comment: With a lot of this it was trial and error unfortunately, I'm still really new to C so I assume I'm making some rookie mistakes with what I've got here, the code I have here is a lot of just what kinda "works" if that makes sense. I used the count variable to basically get it working exactly as I'd like and set the while(count < 20) which was my desired output but not the right overall way to go about it and didn't know how to do it to properly get to the end of a file no matter it's length.

Comment: "I do not think it means what you think it means." As noted, have a look at return value of [fscanf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html).